# django dumpdata ORM + mongoengine

Tags: django, mongoengine

I'm not sure how to handle the following case (thus my question, obviously).

I have a django setup with postgresql to contains all the django model data, but I also have mongoengine managing (let's call them) extended data.

I also have a circular reference between the two (mongo_id points from django model to mongoengine document PK, and db_id points from mongoengine to django model PK).

Obviously, if I run `dumpdata`, I only get django model data. How can I make it to also dump data from mongoengine? Is there a way for me to achieve this?

This is to get a backup of the data. Backup of referenced files can be easily done by just grabbing the file on disk.

I did not define another `DATABASES` in the `settings.py` file (mainly because I was not required to). Is that what I need to do?

Thanks for any pointers.

As a bonus, I would appreciate if I could those mongoengine in the admin interface, but also  the base django models.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can dump your data using [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

In one project we had to move data from one database to another with a significantly different schema so we created a management command that would do that. If you would want to use it in a similar manner it would have the advantage of moving only valid data for your current `Document` definitions and leaving out any possible leftovers from the older ones.

The dumping management command should contain something like

```
from bson import json_utils
json_util.dumps(map(lambda x: x.to_mongo(), SomeDocument.objects.all()))
```